# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Connection refused"

Tags: ios, sockets

I am using `asyncSocket` as client side, aim running my application on iPhone simulator, and the server side coded with C#.
its working perfectly if i try to connect with a server on my LAN but the connection refused with the server out of my LAN.

I'am sure that the same server is working with another client code done on C#.

And this the message i get from *socket* Error:

```
>Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Connection refused"
```

Knowing that i get this message on connect phase before try to send data to server.

Any helping idea is appreciated.

Comment: Havre you tried to reduce this to a minimal test case?  It would help us to answer if you posted your iOS code.  Probably also helpful if you post the C# code from the matching minimal test case that works, too.

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of issues here, but the important things to check include:

- Firewalls that may be restricting incoming access and sending `RST` back to the client (thus simulating a connection refused);
- DNS resolves to the same names from both locations where it works and where it doesn't
- Posting code so we can look at your asyncsocket flow.

I'll update my answer when you post code if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the connection failed, because the host could not be found / resolved. 
Make sure your websocket server is running and accessible for incoming connections. And check if the socket only listening for local ips.